# How do you document sites for future maintenance?

Tags: site-maintenance

I am happy to maintain the sites that I create for customers, but I want to make sure their site will be maintainable into the forseeable future, no matter who maintains it, be it me or someone else.

Suppose, WLOG, the site is running on a VPS somewhere.  As the maintainer, certain aspects of the site's configuration are important to know about (in no particular order):

- VPS login credentials (username and password / SSH key)
- SQL root password
- Web server setup (apache vs nginx, htdocs locations if the VPS services multiple different domains, etc., any customized configuration settings)
- SSL setup (if done via Certbot, otherwise expiry date and any other relevant details)
- Whether site's files exist in a git repository (I almost always run `git init` inside the htdocs folder just to get some level of source control and safety)
- Any other unique aspects of the site's functionality such as SystemD daemons necessary for its operation, etc, etc.

How do you document all of this for the future maintainer?